# Extra weired: variable value reset in middle of process in node

Tags: node.js

I warn you, this is extra weired.

I have the following code where I get the complaintId value from a request then somehow its value is reset:

```
[ 'rp.args ', '60eeba1e1e6ee73bfc4b1350' ]
[ 'found counter by cid: ', '60eeba1e1e6ee73bfc4b1350', ': ', null ]
[ 'finding complaint by id: ', undefined ]
[ 'found complaint by id: ', undefined, ': ', null ]
```

this output comes from here:

```
const complaintById = ComplaintTC.mongooseResolvers.findById().wrapResolve(next => async rp => {
    const complaintId = rp.args._id
    logger.debug("rp.args ", complaintId)

    let counter = await ComplaintVisitCount.findOne({complaintId})
    logger.debug("found counter by cid: ", complaintId, ": ", counter)
    if( counter == null ) {
        logger.debug("finding complaint by id: ", complaintId)
        const complaint = await Complaint.findById(complaintId)
        logger.debug("found complaint by id: ", complaintId, ": ", complaint)
        const {entityGroupId, entityId, _id:complaintId} = complaint
        counter = {entityGroupId, entityId, complaintId, visits:1}
        ComplaintVisitCount.create(counter)
    } else {
        counter.visits++
        await counter.save()
    }
    const toReturn = await next(rp);
    toReturn.stats.visits = counter.visits
    logger.debug("returning complaint with ", counter.visits, " visits: ", toReturn )
    return toReturn
})
```

Any explanations?!!!?

> NOTE:I'm using graphql-compose-mongoose, that's why I have that
> boilerplate code around the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

It was due to the fact that Node becomes unstable when an exception occurs, the line

```
const {entityGroupId, entityId, _id:complaintId} = complaint
```

was causing an exception and that was resetting the variables, in addition, console.log doesn't execute immediately, it is put in a separate 'thread', so when it executed, it was finding the variables null

So to solve it, I had to change the line (which for obscure reasons was throwing "cannot resolve entityGroupId of null" but works great when I access it through its getter)

```
// const {entityGroupId, entityId, _id:complaintId} = complaint
counter = {
    entityGroupId: complaint.entityGroupId,
    entityId: complaint.entityId,
    complaintId: complaint._id,
    visits: 1
}
```